# Concatenation in groovy + bash

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I ran into a small problem when trying to create a shell line in groovy that is stapled from many variables.
Here is what it looks like:

```
sh("""

java -jar Report.jar settings.xml "$startTest" "$durationTest" "$opt" empty iReport:gReport:aReport:pReport="$iReport":"$gReport":"$aReport":"$pReport" $reportName

""")
```

The point is that the command in the shell must run along with the ", which here frames the values of the variables.

However, no matter how much I tried to screen them:

1. Put \ or \\ in front of "
2. Convert the string to 'text' + varibale + 'text'
3. Put the whole shell line in ' and leave " as is, or with the first point taken into account.

None of this works.
Here is an example output:

```
java -jar Report.jar settings.xml '2022-07-04 11:00' 01:00 'Offset=01:00;' empty iReport:gReport:aReport:pReport=true:true:true:true App.result
```

You may notice that for some reason two variables are surrounded by quotation marks ' for themselves, although this is not specified anywhere, which is probably the root of the problem.
Because if me use \", the quotes appear, but not everywhere, in general, me get some mishmash of " and '.

To understand, this is how a groovy file works in the Jenkins pipeline.
Hence my question, under what circumstances do variables start framing themselves '' and how to get rid of it?

Or maybe someone has a different solution to this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you checking the Console logs? The console log does not show the correct interpreted string and could be misleading. Following seems to work for me `echo 'java -jar Report.jar settings.xml \"$startTest\" \"$durationTest\"' > out`

Comment: Yes, that was the Console log.
But even if it doesn't show quite right somewhere, the way the response behaves when running the jar file indicates that there is confusion in " ' (in accepting arguments). That is, it is unlikely that the output ' is just wrong/random here, besides, given that the other variables are not framed by them.

Comment: I tried to do your version too, but in this case " - they just don't exist.